# Adding "Estimated" Shipping & Handling on Checkout

Tags: cart, shipping, shopping

I am trying to add "Estimated" to the Shipping and Handling on my check out. I cannot find the location for the life of me. See screenshot. This is on the final check out and also in the cart.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to app\locale\en_US then modify Mage_Sales.csv

Search the CSV for "Shipping & Handling"  and change the next field over that says the same to "Estimated Shipping & Handling". The idea here is the CSV the field on the left is the text to be translated then the field on the right is the translation.

Comment: I was able to get it to change in the cart but once you login it goes away. Any thoughts?